# convert Sql with inner select to Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to convert this Sql query to LinQ

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
    users
    JOIN products
        ON users.id = products.user_id
WHERE users.id IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM users
    WHERE users.status = 'Online'
)
```

Comment: thank you But i assumed the query is like this to know how deal with inner select

Answer (score 0):

Well, your sql is too complicated (the subquery is useless), so simplify it, and you'll get an easy linq...

```
from u in users
join p in products on u.id equals p.user_id
where u.status == "Online"
select new{u, p};
```

your sql could just be

```
select * 
from users u
join products p on u.id = p.user_id
where u.status = 'Online'
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an inner SELECT at all

```
SELECT *
FROM
    users
    JOIN products
        ON users.id = products.user_id
WHERE
    users.status = 'Online'
```

Now, converting this to a LINQ query is a piece of cake.

Note: You would need an IN-clause with a nested SELECT if you were querying another table that, when joined, would produce more output rows, because it has an 1 : n relation to one of the tables already included in the query.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have these entities:

```
class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

which there is a one-to-many relationship from user to product. So we have:

```
var result = 
    from user in users
    join product in products on user.Id equals product.UserId 
    where user.Status == "online"
    select new { user, product };
```